# Central Tendency of Cauchy distribution

Tags: cauchy-distribution, central-tendency

How do you measure the central tendency of a cauchy distribution?

I'm aware that the mean is not a good measure of the central location for cauchy. Can I use median?

I've been searching with the key word: `central "tendency" of "cauchy" distribution stackexchange` for a long time, and found no satisfactory answer that states how I can measure central tendency of Cauchy distribution. Everybody says that "there exists techniques that deals with...bla...bla..." that never gives a solid example of what there are.

Can someone give me an actual example?

Comment: [Wikipedia on Cauchy Dist'n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) under Estimation: "One simple method is to take the median value of the sample as an estimator of $x_{0}$ [center]...  Other, more precise and robust methods have been developed. For example, the truncated mean of the middle 24% of the sample order statistics produces an estimate for $x_{0}$ that is more efficient than using either the sample median or the full sample mean.

Comment: Also, because the density function is positive at the median, the distribution of the sample median is asymptotically normal for increasing sample size.

Comment: My first search of this site for [Cauchy tendency](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tendenc*+Cauchy) yielded several good answers.  [Variants of this search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=centr*+Cauchy) produce even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the best example of the claim in my
Comment, but here are estimates of the center $10$ of
a Cauchy with scale parameter 1.

Medians and trimmed means were found (in R) for a million
samples of size $n = 100.$ The standard deviation
of the trimmed means is a little smaller.

```
set.seed(922)
h = replicate(10^6, median(rcauchy(100,10)))
mean(h); sd(h)
[1] 9.999961
[1] 0.1585856
a.t = replicate(10^6, mean(rcauchy(100,10), tr=.38))
mean(a.t); sd(a.t)
[1] 10.00004
[1] 0.1535004
```

[image]

Comment: Sampling doesn't seem to have anything to do with a question that is solely about a *distribution.*

Comment: Pondered that, but "Everybody says that 'there exists techniques that deals with...bla...bla...' that never gives a solid example of what there are." made me think OP was asking about estimation. // For the dist'n, isn't the center just the median without further discussion?

Comment: I, too, found the question to be unclear.